# Views contextual filter sorting

Tags: 7, views

I have a view setup with contextual filters to display articles on a block based on node tags. The contextual filter is based on 3 taxonomy vocabularies (ex. A, B, C), each with multiple terms. The default sort order for the view is based on post date.

How can I make a sorting rule that will use A taxonomy with greater precedence than the other two?
I want to display articles that have a match (with the node) on **A** taxonomy before all the other articles that have a match on B or C taxonomies.

This starts as a classic related articles block, but I want to be able just for some nodes to specify some specific articles (mapped with A taxonomy terms) to appear just on those nodes on top of the article list.

Thank you. I’m using Drupal 7, Views 7.x-3.7

EDIT: I feel that it might be needed a more in depth example of this behavior. So we have:

node/1 (with taxonomy vocabularies/terms as follows (for simplicity I'm omitting C))
 | A => red
 | B => apple, lemon

node/2 
 | A => blue 
 | B => apple, lemon, grapefruit

article/1 
 | A => green 
 | B => apple 
 | post date: 2014

article/2 
 | A => red 
 | B => apple, lemon 
 | post date: 2013

Considering the above contextual filters setup, if I have a block listing articles on each of the nodes I will get the same ordering for the articles (1,2) based on date.

What I want is when I'm on node/1, the article/2 to be on top of the list (based on A taxonomy matching), but when I'm on node/2, the regular sorting by post date should apply.

Practically I'm dealing with the same articles listed on all nodes, just the sorting/ordering should be changed based on A taxonomy.